# About CrudRepository and Criteria API

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Spring Boot and now I'm learning to modify data with JPA and Hibernate. I wonder is there any way that I can combine Criteria API of Hibernate with Crud Repository, and add more methods into the repository.

Comment: The Criteria API from Hibernate is deprecated. Or did you mean the JPA Criteria API?

Comment: Oh yes that's it. Sorry my bad

Comment: @TúMaiXuân Maybe [spring data jpa specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your support. I'll take a look

Comment: Oh yes I've succeed it thank you so much.